# Clicking button using keyboard in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am trying to do this by clicking on button using 'A' key in keyboard. I created two frames for this button but the code doesn't work, although there is no error.

Do I need to put anything in my main class? Can anyone help to fix this?

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class controlButton extends MovieClip {      

        public function controlButton() {
            // constructor code
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,clickDown);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,clickUp);
        }

        public function clickDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

         // if the key is A
            if(event.charCode == 65){
                this.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
        }

        public function clickUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

         // if the key is A
            if(event.charCode == 65){
                this.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }

        public function changelabel(newLabel:String):void{

            this.label.text = newLabel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using the actual character codes, just as you would avoid adding an event listener for "click". Instead, use the constants of the `Keyboard` class. While it is unlikely that the codes will ever change, this does make it future proof. (so instead of `event.charCode == 65` use `event.charCode == Keyboard.A`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button will never receive any *KeyboardEvent*. You should add your event listeners directly to the stage. Of course, you have to obtain a link to the stage. Anyways:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class controlButton extends MovieClip {


    public function controlButton() {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage (e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
                    //stage is no longer null here
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,clickDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,clickUp);
    }


    public function clickDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

     // if the key is A
         if(event.charCode == 65){
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
        } 


    }

    public function clickUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

     // if the key is A
         if(event.charCode == 65){
                this.gotoAndStop(1);
             }
    }



    public function changelabel(newLabel:String):void{

        this.label.text = newLabel;
    }
}

}
```

As you can see, you should add KeyboardEvent listeners to the stage right after the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE fires.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to AS3. when I implemented your code, I encountered an error of "access of undefined property onAddedToStage. Where should I define this?

Comment: OMG, sorry, I forgot to name the function. It was just 

        private function (e:Event)

Now it's 

         private function onAddedToStage (e:Event)

I've corrected the answer, try to copy-pase it again